# Server key (for legacy protocols) - authorizes your app server for access to Google services . Meaning?

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, moengage

Do Server key (for legacy protocols) gives access to other fcm/gcm projects associated with a developer account .
In my case , 
1. I already have a **gcm project(server key1)** and I created new **fcm project(server key2)** for the same app. 
2. Now my **new app** with **fcm** and my **old app** with **gcm** are both generating tokens and sending to my messaging platform ( Moengage ) 
3. In **moengage** I have entered **only** **server key1**(gcm server key)

Problem : Although I have not entered server key for **fcm** . Still my new app is **receiving notification**.

So , I want to ask ***whether the server key gives access to all the fcm/gcm associated with the developer account ????***

If this is not the case ,what can be the reason for such behaviour .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each FCM/GCM project has a different Server key does not give access to all other associated accounts.
The order in which you are passing the token to the MoEngage SDK would matter here. The second token sent to MoEngage SDK will be the one which will eventually get saved and will be used to target the users whenever you send out a campaign from MoEngage platform.
Can you please provide more details about the integration when is the FCM token passed when is the GCM token passed, if the app is registering for push token or the SDK is doing. I'll be able to help better with these details available.

I would recommend you to drop and e-mail to support@moengage.com with above details and the Application name on MoEngage for faster response/resolution.

PS: I am a member of the MoEngage Team.